# Can Cunning Action be taken more than once per turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, actions, rogue

The [rogue's Cunning Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#CunningAction-345) feature states:

> Starting at 2nd level, your quick thinking and agility allow you to move and act quickly. You can take a bonus action **on each of your turns** in combat. This action can be used only to take the Dash, Disengage, or Hide action.

<sup>Player's Handbook, p. 96</sup>

If I somehow could take more than one Bonus Action within a single turn, could Cunning Action be used twice?  My concern is that it says "on *each* of your turns" (emphasis added) and I am unsure if that means it can only be used once per turn irrespective of available actions or if I'm reading too much into that phrasing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> You can take **a** bonus action on each of your turns in combat.

The "a" seems singular to me so one bonus action. If RAW wanted you to use the class feature multiple times it would read "You can use your bonus actions to..."

Although I think it's a moot point; as far as I know there isn't a way to obtain multiple bonus actions in the same turn.

Comment: Yeah that's what my second paragraph was saying, I am pretty sure there is no way outside of homebrewed rules to have more than one bonus action in a turn.

Answer (score 4):

The text in *[Cunning Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#CunningAction)* as written applies to **both** the turns a 17th level Rogue with *Thief's Reflexes* gets during the first round. If it said "once per round" rather than "on each of your turns", it would be unavailable on a Thief's second turn.

Comment: That involves multiple turns - there's still only one bonus action per turn. This answer doesn't technically answer the question as asked, so you might want to expand it a bit more to address the question directly before explaining (as you do here) how you can have multiple bonus actions per round.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> If I somehow could take more than one Bonus Action within a single turn, could Cunning Action be used twice?

If I was the DM the answer would be yes. As the rules are written you can only take one Bonus Action on a single turn. The text for Cunning Action is written with this in mind, so it wouldn't make sense for the rules to take into account a situation where you can take more than one Bonus Action. If you get the chance to use more than one Bonus Action on one turn, we're moving in to homebrew territory and can't make any conclusions based on the rules. Whatever homebrew feature allows you multiple Bonus Actions, or the DM, would have to address it's interaction with Cunning Action.