# If you use two Scimitars of Speed, do you get 2 bonus action attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, actions, bonus-action

The description for a [*Scimitar of Speed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/scimitar-of-speed) says:

> ...you can make one attack with it as a **bonus action** on each of your turns.

The *general rule* for [Bonus Actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions) is stated as such:

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose
> which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

In 5e, don't *specific* rules beat *general* rules? In that case, wouldn't the specific rule that each *Scimitar of Speed* allows a Bonus Action attack take precedence over the general "only 1 Bonus Action" rule?

**If you use two Scimitars of Speed, do you get 2 bonus action attacks?**

Comment: Related: [Can Cunning Action be taken more than once per turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132500/can-cunning-action-be-taken-more-than-once-per-turn), [How to get more Bonus Actions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113862/how-to-get-more-bonus-actions)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### No. You can only ever take one bonus action on a turn.

The [*scimitar of speed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/scimitar-of-speed) lets you use your bonus action to make an attack, regardless of what you do with your action:

> In addition, you can make one attack with it as a bonus action on each of your turns.

However, the rules on [bonus actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions) state (emphasis mine):

> Various class features, spells, and other abilities **let you take an additional action on your turn called a bonus action**. The Cunning Action feature, for example, allows a rogue to take a bonus action. You can take a bonus action only when a special ability, spell, or other feature of the game states that you can do something as a bonus action. You otherwise don't have a bonus action to take.
>
> **You can take only one bonus action on your turn**, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

The *scimitar of speed* doesn't **grant** you a bonus action; it gives you a way to **use** your bonus action. You might have a million ways to use that bonus action, but nothing in the game (so far) ever changes your limit of 1 bonus action per turn. (Contrast the fighter's [Action Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ActionSurge-193) feature or the [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell, which do explicitly let you take an additional action on a turn.)

There is no "specific" rule of the *scimitar of speed* that changes the limit on the number of bonus actions you can take in a turn.

Comment: Nice answer; as a counterpoint to the question's "specific beats general" argument, I feel the need to link [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/97886/15469), since the same principle applies here - if it worked in this scenario, it'd work with *everything* that gives you a way to use your bonus action, and the once per turn restriction would be meaningless.

Comment: @Miniman You logic makes sense, especially in light of your linked answer.

Comment: Sorry to necro, but it came up in another question. The line is, _"...you can make one attack with it as a bonus action ..."_ And you have two "it"s. Is it possible that the reading would be "each scimitar gets one attack on your bonus attack", not "each scimitar get one attack per bonus attack, but you only ever get one bonus attack so only one scimitar works"? In other words, you're not doubling the number of "bonus attack"s, you're double the number of attacks that can happen on a single "bonus attack".

Comment: @MivaScott: No. If "you can make one attack with it as a bonus action", that's what you're using your single bonus action to do. You're not making one attack with the scimitar as part of some broader bonus action; that single attack *is* what you do as your bonus action.

Answer (score 12):

**Answer is no though not for the reasons given (trick question?)**

The point is made moot due to attunement issue.  The scimitar of speed is an attunement required item (per
[item description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4752-scimitar-of-speed)) and according to the DMG (highlighting mine):

> [...] Additionally, **a creature can’t attune to more than one copy of an item**. For example, a creature can’t attune to more than one ring of protection at a time.

If you had some homebrew variant, say a shortsword of speed, AND a scimitar of speed, are they technically different?  Up to the DM at that point, but V2Blast in their [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/168096/63061) has already made the case against having more that a single attack per bonus action in this situation.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and maybe visit the [help] if you did not alredy done it! Happy gaming!

Comment: Thanks Eddymage for the help reformatting this answer.